# Erlang receive after 0

Tags: erlang

Say I have an Erlang process whose message queue currently looks like this:

```
msg1
msg2
{timeout, Ref1, some_atom}
msg3
msg4
```

What the message queue will look like if I do:

```
receive
    {timeout, Ref1, some_atom} ->
        0
after 0
    false
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try this in the shell to find out:

```
1> Pid = spawn(fun F() -> receive start -> receive {timeout, Ref1, some_atom} -> F() after 0 -> ok end end end).
<0.47.0>
2> Pid ! msg1.
msg1
3> Pid ! msg2.
msg2
4> Pid ! {timeout, erlang:make_ref(), some_atom}.
{timeout,#Ref<0.0.8.133>,some_atom}
5> Pid ! msg3.
msg3
6> Pid ! msg4.
msg4
7> erlang:process_info(Pid, messages).
{messages,[msg1,msg2,
           {timeout,#Ref<0.0.8.133>,some_atom},
           msg3,msg4]}
8> Pid ! start.
start
9> erlang:process_info(Pid, messages).
{messages,[msg1,msg2,msg3,msg4]}
```

- Command 1 creates a process `Pid` waiting to receive a `start` atom, after which it performs the `receive` you specified in your question.
- Commands 2-6 create the message queue in `Pid` matching your question.
- Command 7 verifies that the `Pid` message queue is what we expect.
- Command 8 sends the `start` atom to cause `Pid` to execute the `receive` you specified in your question, and then go back and wait for another `start` message.
- Command 9 checks the `Pid` message queue again. As we can see, the code received the `{timeout, Ref1, some_atom}` tuple and left `msg1` and similar atoms in the queue.

The results of command 9 are exactly what we expect, due to Erlang's selective receive capability, which causes it to look through the message queue to find the first match when receiving messages. If no messages matched in this case, the `after 0` clause would instead execute, which in this code would mean the spawned function would finish and `Pid` would exit.

Comment: You can even send to the shell (`Ref1 = make_ref(), [self() ! M || M <- [msg1, msg2, {timeout, Ref1, some_atom}, msg3, msg4]], receive {timeout, Ref1, some_atom} -> ok after 0 -> ok end, flush().`)

Comment: Yes, the `after 0` clause is guaranteed to search the message queue for matching messages **before** timing out immediately.